# Add new column to table and fill with the data of 2 other columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns: `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

How can I add a third column to my table that is `ColumnA` divided by `ColumnB`?

I know this seems simple, but I have been unable to find the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
SELECT ColumnA, 
       ColumnB, 
       (ColumnA / ColumnB) as ColumnC 
  FROM myTable
```

or to actually add a new column and fill it with the result of `ColumnA` divided by `ColumnB` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD `ColumnC` INT NOT NULL;
UPDATE `myTable` SET ColumnC = (ColumnA / ColumnB);
```

**[You can see more options about the `ALTER TABLE` syntax here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)**

Comment: I want to actually add a new column into the table (permanently)

Comment: Thanks, Prix.  I only had to make a minor adjustment to make the above work.  I added `COLUMN` to the line: `ALTER TABLE ``myTable`` ADD COLUMN``ColumnC`` INT NOT NULL;`.  I'm executing this with HeidiSQL and it didn't work without `COLUMN`.

Comment: @Mr.Kinn well I tested it on phpMyAdmin exactly as it is, and worked just fine regardless glad you found out how to fix it for heidiSQL.

Comment: OK, I'll leave my comment up in case someone using Heidi comes across this in the future.  Thanks again.